# Unzip list of files that are specified in txt files

Tags: bash, zip

I have a txt file that contains a list of file names.
In bash, how do I unzip only those files specified in the list from a zip file?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
unzip -q /path/to/zipfile $(cat thetxtfile)
```

Of course, this command needs to be issued in a directory which is preferably empty to begin with.

Note that if there are spaces into your file names, this won't work and you need to do this instead:

```
while read thefile; do unzip -q /path/to/zipfile "$thefile"; done <thetxtfile
```

Comment: That will break depending on how the files are named. Spaces, for example, will be problematic. It will also fail if you have too many files, and exceed your platform's number of arguments limit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a list of files at the command line, `xargs` is almost always the best answer -- it handles file names with spaces cleanly, and it gets around the limit of the number of arguments. I would suggest this:

```
tr '\n' '\0' <filelist.txt | xargs -0 unzip -q /path/to/zipfile
```

The use of `tr '\n' '\0' <filelist.txt` takes your list of files and substitutes nul characters for new lines. `xargs -0` reads a nul delimited list of files and tacks that onto the agument list of the following command.

This will break if your list of filenames uses '\r\n' or '\r' style end of lines.

Comment: `xargs -d '\n'` is equivalent to the combination of `tr` and `xargs -0`. It's also worth noting that according to the xargs man page, "Unix  filenames  can  contain blanks and newlines", so I guess it's impossible to solve this problem in all cases since the input is ambiguous.

Comment: Good point. Theoretically, I suppose that the text file could be edited with nul characters (or some delimiter not used in the file names), then this could be piped directly in to xargs, using a -0 or -d<delim> argument. In practice, I find that it's best to simply take anyone who puts new lines in file names and execute them publicly as a warning to others.